# Fixing the x axis and the gridline of a plot in r

Tags: r, plot, position

I am trying to visualise data on a graph with R.

The code below works perfectly but the gridlines seem to be lost (see the image below).

```
with(res_final, plot(position_aa, mean_res, main="Hydrophobicity",
               xlab="Amino acid position",
               ylab="Eisenberg scale"))
with(res_final, points(position_aa, mean_res, pch=10, cex=0.5))
.col <- rgb(0, 0, 0, .25)  ## alpha .25 for transparency
abline(h=axTicks(3), lty=3, col=.col)
abline(v=seq(-10:14), lty=3, col=.col)
```

[image: Image of the plot]

1. I have positions from -10 to 14. How can I make the x axis with every single position separately labelled?
2. How can I add the gridlines to the plot below so that it is visible for each position from the x axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided any data,but the following is a reasonable approximation:

```r
set.seed(69)

res_final <- data.frame(position_aa = seq(-10, 14, 1),
                        mean_res = c(runif(10, -0.5, 0.25), 
                                     runif(4, 0.5, 1.25),
                                     runif(11, -0.5, 0.25)))
```

The main problem with your code is your use of `seq`, which isn't doing what you think it is. The way to get a sequence between -10 and 14 is `seq(-10, 14, 1)` or `seq(-10, 14)`. This change will allow your grid lines to appear as expected.

For your second problem, you can add an `axis` call using `pos = 1` and the `at` argument to specify the breaks on the axis. You'll need to ensure that the plot area is wide enough (or the axis text is small enough) that some of the numbers don't get suppressed.

```r
with(res_final, plot(position_aa, mean_res, main = "Hydrophobicity",
               xlab = "Amino acid position",
               ylab = "Eisenberg scale"))
axis(pos = 1,  at = seq(-10, 14, 1))
with(res_final, points(position_aa, mean_res, pch = 10, cex = 0.5))
.col <- rgb(0, 0, 0, .25)
abline(h = axTicks(3), lty = 3, col = .col)
abline(v = seq(-10, 14, 1), lty = 3, col = .col)
```

[image]

For completeness, the equivalent in ggplot would be:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(res_final, aes(position_aa, mean_res)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 5, fill = "white") +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 2, fill = "black") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-10, 14)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 15),
        plot.title.position = "plot",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(title = "Hydrophobicity",
       x = "Amino acid position",
       y = "Eisenberg scale")
```

[image]